# Iterating multiple variables in ForEach

Tags: powershell, foreach

Using the below code I'm trying to find servers that have mismatching power status in our SQL database (manually entered, so prone to mistakes) and vCenter. I doesn't quite work though since  at `-And $VM.PowerState -like "PoweredOn"` it gets the status of all servers (about 500) rather than just one server at a time, causing the statement to always fail.

```
# $VM = List of Virtual Machines, properties Name and PowerState
# $ServerList = List of Servers, properties Name and Status.

foreach ($serverEntry in $ServerList) {
    if ($VM.Name -contains $serverEntry.Name -And $VM.PowerState -like "PoweredOn" -And $serverEntry.Status -like "In Use") {
        Stuff will happen
    } else {
        Some other stuff
    }
 }
```

I tried a nested loop but can't get that to work, and since the servers aren't listed in the same order I can't use a simple counter (`$i`).

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($serverEntry in $ServerList)
{
    $currentVM = $VM | ? {$_.Name -eq $serverEntry.Name}
    if ($currentVM.PowerState -like "PoweredOn" -And $serverEntry.Status -like "In Use") {Stuff will happen} else {Some other stuff}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the elements of the list `$VM` in a hashtable:

```
$vmlist = @{}
$VM | ForEach-Object { $vmlist[$_.Name] = $_ }
```

That gives you a data structure where you can access your VM objects by the name of the VM. Use that in the `$ServerList` loop:

```
foreach ($serverEntry in $ServerList) {
    if ($vmlist[$serverEntry.Name].PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn' -and $serverEntry.Status -eq 'In Use') {
        # do some
    } else {
        # do other
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost but not quite. In Use is getting matched/true with both PoweredOn and PoweredOff.The only time it´s not matched and goes to the else part is when the the Status is something other then In Use (for example 'removed' or 'waiting for removal'

Comment: I doubt that. Please provide evidence.

Comment: Show your modified code. Show sample input data. Show the generated output.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/lbdq9 Here is sample output, the PS is the output from your code and the Excel is a refrence list i created earlier 

http://pastebin.com/CpUpvPU0 Here is my updated code

Comment: The excel list can also be considerd the input data since its a export-csv result of my $Table and $VMList variables

Comment: You have two separate inputs, `$ServerList` and `$VMList`. Already merged data in an Excel table is not helpful.

Comment: Right but the input is the same the only diffrence is instead of having 2 identical columns with the servernames twice i only use one coulmn in the Excel list But anyway input is like this:

$Table which contain 2 properties: Servernames (Property Name) and Status (Property Status). $VMLIst is a result of     $VMList = Get-VM | select -Property Name, PowerState

Comment: Please provide the information I've asked for in your question. Otherwise you're on your own.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://imgur.com/a/GdCTO  In these snippets the servernames don´t match since the servernames aren´t in the same alphabetical order in the variables. That shouldnt be relevant though. The lists are also much longer then those 10ish servers.